# Styling parent element with less

Tags: html, css, less

I'm looking for a way to apply styling to the parent element of another element, using LESS/CSS.

For example:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <span class="chosen">Hello World</span>
</div>
```

I need the CSS to apply styling to the  element given the specific class of the child.

**CSS:**

```
div {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: 'blue'
}
```

Perhaps something like:

```
.chosen {
    div& {
        height: 50px;
        background-color: 'blue'
    }
}
```

Any direction greatly appreciated.

(Apologies for lack of fiddle, unsure how to include LESS)

Comment: This is neither possible with CSS nor LESS (since LESS transpiles to CSS in the first place). See the duplicate. JSFiddle does not support LESS, but JS Bin does.

Comment: Thanks very much, sorry for the dup.

Comment: No worries. Duplicates aren't necessarily a bad thing so long as they're not straight-up direct copy posts.